# Fetch registered user posts to another page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress website on which the main posts are coming on the homepage . All i need is that , If a registered user do post on website ,its posts should come on a different page where only the user posts should come. how to fetch registered user post to a different page rather than homepage where main admin posts are coming .
please help.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the author ID.
For index.php page use

```
$posts = get_posts('post_type=post&author=1');
```

And for the other page exclude this ID.

```
$posts = get_posts('post_type=post&author=-1');
```